# Prove if $ x \in V_a$, $x \subseteq V_a$

Tags: set-theory

Prove if $x \in V_a$, $x \subseteq V_a$, where $V_a$ is collection of sets such that $a \in$ collection of ordinal numbers. My thoughts:

Do induction on well ordering somehow.

For $a = 0$:

$V_a = V_0 = \emptyset$
If $ x \in V_0$, $x = \emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$

Hence true.

Suppose the statement is true for some $a$.
For $a+1$:

If $x \in V_{a+1}$ then $x \in \mathscr{P}(V_a)$

($V_{a+1} = \mathscr{P}(V_a)$)

By definition of $x$ and $\mathscr{P}(V_a)$, $ x \subseteq V_{a+1}$.

For $V_\beta = \bigcup_{α<\beta} V_α$ where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

If $x \in V_\beta$, then since $a < a+1 < \beta$ and hence $V_a \in \mathscr{P}(V_a) = V_{a+1} \subset V_\beta$.

I'm not sure where to go from here (limit ordinal part) or if I have been doing it correctly before that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your argument for $a=0$ is not correct.

Comment: The induction hypothesis covers the case of $\beta$ a limit.

Comment: I’m not convinced by the successor case either. The argument is: If $x\in V_{a+1}$, then $x\subseteq V_a$. So for any $y\in x$,  $y\in V_a$, and thus by the induction hypothesis, $y\subseteq V_a.$ So $x\subseteq P(V_a)=V_{a+1}$.

Comment: For the limit case note that the union of transitive sets is a transitive set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: While the argument for $a=0$ is certainly not the right one, in the most annoying and formal sense of the word, it is not incorrect.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, the $”x=\emptyset”$ part is irrelevant, not wrong, per se.